# What does 'gold to boot' means in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

So the context is about a football manager's wife. The person wrote the following about her

> His Missus never left(Liverpool), and she's a bit of gold to boot.

What does it mean gold to boot, does it mean she's rich?

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "she's a bit of gold" (and I'm a native speaker), but "to boot" is similar to "as well". "he's not only intelligent, he's handsome to boot".

Comment: See [Why do we say "to boot"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9538/16310)

Comment: This sentence needs more context to determine whether "she's a bit of gold to boot" is short for "she has a bit of gold to boot", or "she is a bit of gold to boot".  "She has" would imply that she has valuable assets (such as cash) that can be spent or sold. "She is" would imply that she has very admirable qualities, like the proverbial woman whose "[price is above rubies](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+31%3A10-31&version=KJV)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[To boot](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/to-boot)* is an idiomatic expression used to emphasize something additional; as Macmillan has it,

> used for emphasizing the last point in a list of comments or criticisms
>
> > The vegetables were overcooked and tasteless, and cold to boot.

The [OALD entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/boot#boot_1__196) marks it as *old-fashioned or humorous*, which I don't wholly agree with, but your quote is colloquial to be sure. I would "translate" it as

> His wife never left Liverpool; moreover, she is a woman of independent means.

or

> His wife never left Liverpool, and furthermore has some wealth of her own.

Answer (score 2):

"She's" here is short for "she has", rather than the more common "she is". As Sarah points out in comments, "to boot" is an idiom that means "as well", "additionally", or "on top of everything else". One might have a bit of gold literally, which would generally be a sign of some wealth, or it might be figuratively (having money in the bank).

So it means "Not only did his Missus never leave Liverpool, she's also rather well off financially."